# Array Instantiation Error

Tags: c#, arrays, initialization

I have two classes:

```
public class SubObject {
    public int id;
}

public class Object {
    public SubObject[] SubObjects;
}
```

And I have one array:

```
public Object[] Objects;
```

When I try to instantiate this array:

```
public void InstantiateArrays(int objectsSize, int subObjectsSize) {
    Objects = new Object[objectsSize];
    foreach (Object obj in Objects) {
        obj.SubObjects = new SubObject[subObjectsSize];
    }
}
```

I am receiving this error:

> An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in
>   **** but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Side-note: naming a class `Object` is a terrible idea.

Comment: It is only a demonstration of my code, the original name of the classes are not the same to the demonstration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line:

```
Objects = new Object[objectsSize];
```

You create an array. The *elements* of the array are initialized to the default values for the type. Since it's an array of *objects*, this default value is `null`.

Within the loop, you're trying to access the field `SubObjects` of an object that's `null`:

```
obj.SubObjects = new SubObject[objectsSize];
```

A quick fix is to use a `for` loop and instantiate the objects in your loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < subObjectSize; i++)
{
    Objects[i] = new Object();
    Objects[i].SubObjects = new SubObject[subObjectsSize];
}
```

Also note that naming one of your classes `Object` is bad practice, since this is the name of the class at the root of the object heirarchy.

Comment: Whoa! It solved my problem, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is invalid:

```
Objects = new Object[objectsSize];
foreach (Object obj in Objects) {
```

this is because the first line will create an array that consists of `null` references, which is the default value of an `Object` reference in C#. Using `foreach` does not let you overwrite references.

You need to use array indexes to set array elements:

```
for(int i = 0; i < this.Objects.Length; i++ ) {
    this.Objects[i] = new SubObject[ subObjectSize ];
}
```

Note that using `Object` is generally a bad idea as it forces you to use casting. If you have a tiered object hiearchy then use strong typing or better yet: generics, where appropriate.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error.